# Loading the first 5 images from google with specific keyword

Tags: image, loading, google-image-search

I'm trying to load the first 5 image that comes up on google when I type a given keyword in my app. So let's say if the keyword was "Butter" I want to load the first 5 images that com up on google if you type butter.

I've been looking at the Github project SDWebImages (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), but it looks like you can only load the images if you have the url of the image.

Anybody know how I can do what I described, or anybody that can point me in the right direction as to what I should look at to do it.

Comment: Seems like you need a way to get the specific ending link from google images.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but does it have to be from Google? You might have more luck with the [Flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) since Google has deprecated their image search API.

Comment: The images I need is mostly food images, so lets say if there's a recipe for some sort of chicken dish, I then need to load the first 5 images of that chicken dish from google, and then show them in my app, so people can see what the recipe is for. I have been Searching on Flicker and it seems like they dont really have that sort of images, so I'm sure google would be the best choice here, but thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Google has deprecated their [image search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide) and you are now supposed to use [custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview) which supports images.  You will need to [sign up for an API key](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).  When you make your search request you need to set your [searchType](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) parameter to image.

Comment: Is there no way around using the google custom search? because they limit you to 100 queries/day, before billing.

Comment: You can always load images.google.com and parse the html of the page.  Thats a lot more work.

Comment: If you actually want to parse the html and scrape the images I recommend using this pod: https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup